# Billing Solutions: Invoice "Mail Later via QuickBooks" Checkbox: Default to Checked

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, invoices

How can I set the "Mail Later via QuickBooks" checkbox to default to checked?  I haven't figured this out yet, so I'm forced to go to the Send/Ship tab and check it manually for each invoice.  Please tell me there's a better way.  I'd love to have it always checked for every new invoice by default.

Edit:  I'd also like to be able to check the box programmatically through QBXML, but according to my question on the Intuit Developer Network Forums, it's not possible.  https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=56&threadid=19064&enterthread=y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This field is not exposed through the SDK or IDS.

Comment: OK, but what about the focus of the question:  can I set the checkbox to default to checked?  How can the rest of the QuickBooks community be content with clicking the Send/Ship tab and then checking the checkbox for every, single, stinkin' invoice?  And what if I forget it on one invoice out of the hundreds we send out?

Comment: As sad as it is, I'm afraid you are correct.  I've been looking on and off for months, and Intuit seems to have no way of solving this through QBXML.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the invoice is recurring you may save it on the memorized transaction. when the new invoice is created it will automatically have it selected if selected on the memorized transaction.